# ¿Como puedo convertir un array en múltiples Strings en PHP?

Tags: php, array, string, php8, metodología

Buen día comunidad, espero puedan ayudarme con este problema. Tengo un arreglo llamado:

```
$persona = ["nombre","apellidos","edad","profesión","estudios","estado_civil","etc"];
```

Lo que quiero hacer, es convertir cada posición del arreglo en un string, sin usar el bucle for, ya que los métodos implode(), Json_encode()...etc, me convierten todo el arreglo en una sola cadena String. El objetivo es que cada campo del arreglo se convierta a String, para poder manipularlos por separado sin la necesidad de recorrer dicho arreglo con bucle for.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Y el bucle foreach lo puedes usar?  ¿O no puedes usar ningun tipo de bucle?

Comment: No, de ningún bucle.

Comment: *...convertir cada posición del arreglo en un string...* pero si cada elemento del arreglo ya es un string, entonces con `$persona[0]`, `$persona[1]`, etc vas accediendo a cada elemento. ¿Puedes ilustrar cómo es la salida que quieres?

Comment: Tal vez te pueda servir la función [list()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.list.php), o bien, [desestructurar](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring).

Comment: Como bien dice @aeportugal, la forma de hacer lo que quieres es mediante los índices de cada valor. Ahora bien, ¿sabes de antemano cuántos elementos tendrá el array o no? Si es un array que en un contexto puede tener `N` elementos y en otro contexto `M` elementos, entonces no te servirá, porque será difícil controlar un posible acceso a un índice no existente. Sea como sea, creo que falta contexto, ¿quizá quieres resolver de este modo un problema que realmente está en otro nivel (error de lógica al obtener/diseñar los datos, etc)?

Comment: Si, lo que busco, es que cada posición del arreglo se convierta en una variable independiente ya sea string, int o cualquiera, se que suena extraño, por que puedo declarar cada variable por separado, pero los datos del arreglo ya se me proporcionan, entonces lo que busco es como un método que recorra el arreglo y que me retorne las variables, ya que las quiero manipular por separado, y si lo hago con un bucle, tengo que poner la lógica dentro del bucle para manipular los elementos del arreglo . por que si lo hago fuera del bucle ya no puedo acceder a los elementos

Comment: A ver, es que lo que estás diciendo es algo como: quiero hacer lo que hace un bucle, pero no quiero un bucle... o sea, *ni contigo ni sin ti* ... Aclárate. Quizá si explicas lo que quieres hacer a posteriori con esos datos podremos ayudarte mejor. Más que nada creo que hay un error de concepto y estoy casi seguro de que la manera correcta de resolver tu problema no es de este modo, por más maravilloso que te parezca.

Comment: @Navita he modificado mi respuesta teniendo en cuenta tus comentarios, creo que con eso te debería servir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actualización**

Lo que buscas es diferente a lo que preguntabas en origen. No se trata de convertir cada elemento a un string si no a extraer cada elemento como una variable independiente.

Para ello dispones de la función [`extract`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

En principio esta función está orientada a arrays asociativos, pero dispones del flag `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` que añade un prefijo a cada uno de los elementos extraídos usando el índice del elemento del array como sufijo, con lo que podrías hacer la conversión.

```
$valores = ["Pedro","Pérez",15,"carpintero","FP","soltero",666444333];
extract($valores, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "out");
```

De esta manera se habrán generado variables `$out_0`, `$out_1`,... para cada elemento del array:

```
echo $out_0.' - '.$out_1.' - '.$out_2.' - '.$out_3.' - '.$out_4.' - '.$out_5.' - '.$out_6;

/*
Pedro - Pérez - 15 - carpintero - FP - soltero - 666444333
*/
```

---

**Respuesta original**

Utiliza array_map (internamente va a iterar, pero no estás usando un bucle al uso).

[`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php) devuelve un array después de haber aplicado una función a cada uno de los elementos del array de entrada.

Si queremos convertir un elemento a string podemos hacer simplemente:

```
(string) $a;
```

Con esto, podemos combinar los dos conceptos:

```
$persona = ["Pedro","Pérez",15,"carpintero","FP","soltero",666444333];
$out = array_map(function ($a){return (string) $a;}, $persona);
```

Y nos generaría una salida en la que cada elemento del array ya es un string:

```
$out = ["Pedro","Pérez","15","carpintero","FP","soltero","666444333"];
```

Comment: Trata de especificar cómo la función resolvería el problema del OP y cómo se vería la posible salida de datos.

Comment: Hecho, aunque la pregunta del OP según los comentarios creo que buscaba obtener otra solución

Comment: Añadida respuesta para la situación actual

Answer (score 0):

Use `implode()` y `str_replace()` para lo que usted busca.

```
<?php 

$persona = array("nombre", "apellido");

$implode = implode(" ", $persona);

$nuevoNombre = "Carlos";

$nuevoApellido = "Vera";

$replace = str_replace("nombre apellido", "$nuevoNombre $nuevoApellido", $implode);

echo $replace; // resultado: "Carlos Vera"
```